# AS3 Add Child at the position of another Child

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey I have got some cavemen that when they build huts I want the huts to be added at the coords of the caveman I last clicked on which requires the ability to know exactly what caveman the user clicked on/tapped. Here is the code for spawning in the cavemen:

```
//////////////////////
///Starting Cavemen///
//////////////////////
var cavemanVar:Array = new Array(50);
for (var i:Number = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    cavemanVar[i] = 0;
}
var foo:MovieClip = new btn_caveman();
cavemanVar[0] = addChildAt(foo, 7);
var bar:MovieClip = new btn_caveman();
cavemanVar[1] = addChildAt(bar, 7);
cavemanVar[0].x = 335.50;
cavemanVar[0].y = 316.55;
cavemanVar[1].x = 335.50;
cavemanVar[1].y = 369.5;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, example2);
function example2 (evt:Event) {
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (cavemanVar[i] != 0)
        {
            cavemanVar[i].addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, btn_cavemanMenu3);
        }
    }
}    

function option1CavemenSpawn():void {
    trace("using option 1")
    actions += 1;
    score += 5;
    remaningActions += 1;
    updateTextBox();
    var foo6:MovieClip = new btn_caveman();
    cavemanVar[2] = addChildAt(foo6, 7);
    cavemanVar[2].x = 352.10;
    cavemanVar[2].y = 260.80 + Math.random() * (392.40 - 260.80);
    }
```

Any help would be great, I have tried using 'cavemanVar', 'cavemanVar[2]', 'cavemanVar[i]' and nothing is what I want it to be.
Hope I explained it properly it's a tricky thing to explain. I also have a move caveman feature I want to implement which would select the last clicked/tapped caveman and move it where the user clicks/taps so can any of this be done and if so how?

EDIT:

```
function btn_cavemanMenu3(event:TouchEvent):void {
    btn_cavemanM.gotoAndStop(2);
    trace('2');
    allowBuildHut();
    cancelTapCaveman();
    allowTapCavemanClose();
    if (remaningActions <= 2 || stone <= 29) {
            cancelBuildHut();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like,

```
cavemanVar[i].addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, onTap);

function onTap(e:TouchEvent):void {
    var caveman:btn_caveman = e.currentTarget as btn_caveman;
    trace("caveman tapped --- (" + caveman.x + ", " + caveman.y + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, some things I noticed right away:

- Attaching eventListeners with each frame, again and again. This will make your game slow if you make your game bigger. I'm not sure, but I think multiple event listeners with the same arguments don't stack, so it's not THAT bad.
- Missing a return type for `example2`.

But aside from that, I think the reason that what you're trying to do doesn't work is because you're not referencing the selected caveman in your `btn_cavemanMenu3` function. Via `event.currentTarget` you can reference the tapped caveman.

Currently, your question name and your question description conflict. What exactly do you wish to achieve? What is working and what isn't working right now?

Comment: updated. I'm still not entirely sure what you want to do. What's the process you're trying to create, which steps does that process contain, and which of those steps work, and which don't?